# Ordenar consulta com paginate cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, classificação

```
 $this->paginate = [
       'contain' => ['Unidades'],
       'fields' =>['PontoDeColetas.id','PontoDeColetas.nome','PontoDeColetas.status','Unidades.id','Unidades.nome'],
       'order' => ['Unidades.nome' => 'desc']
 ];
```

Como mostro acima, estou tentando organizar pelo nome de uma classe filha, mas não funciona. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Unidades'],
        'fields' => ['PontoDeColetas.nome','PontoDeColetas.status','Unidades.id','Unidades.nome'],
        'sortWhitelist'  =>  ['nome','status','Unidades.nome'],
        'order' => ['status' => 'desc','nome' => 'asc']
        ];
```

Resolvi com essa linha 'sortWhitelist'.

Comment: Perfeito, parece ser um recurso novo do CakePHP 3, eu não conhecia. Você pode marcar sua própria resposta como a correta neste caso.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(
              'contain' => array('Unidades')
              'fields' => array('PontoDeColetas.id','PontoDeColetas.nome','PontoDeColetas.status','Unidades.id','Unidades.nome'),
              'order' => array('Unidades.nome' => 'desc'),


            );

$this->paginate = $options;
```

Tente isso.

Answer (score 0):

Quando se usa `contain`, o **CakePHP** realiza várias *queries*, tantas quanta forem incluídas. Então você não pode realizar condições, ordenar, agrupar e etc em sua classe principal a partir das classes do `contain`.

Então se sua classe que será paginada é a **PontoDeColetas**, é ela que você consegue ordenar na chave *order* que você colocou no seu código.

Agora, você consegue ordenar **Unidades** que estão contidas em **PontoDeColetas**, que é só incluir o *order*, assim:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Unidades' => ['order' => ['Unidades.nome' => 'DESC']]],
    'fields' => ['PontoDeColetas.id','PontoDeColetas.nome','PontoDeColetas.status','Unidades.id','Unidades.nome']
];
```

De outra forma, você terá que usar [`joins`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins), daí é um pouco diferente a solução.